# Simulate MiddleClick behaviour with navigateToURL(request, "_blank")?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I'm trying to make a custom button in flash, which when clicked, will open a URL in a new tab/window, WITHOUT stealing focus from the current Flash tab/window.

The classic `navigateToURL(request, "_blank");` will open the new tab, but also bring it up. I want it to stay away minding it's own business, just as if I had middle-clicked on a link on a HTML page.

Is this possibru?

Cheers!

### [EDIT]

I would at least want the user to be able to see a short tween of the currently clicked thumbnail moving and fading to the upper-right corner of the gallery, to symbolize the fact that it's opening in a new tab. This isn't possible because as soon as you click, the new tab steals focus, and leaves my flash thumbnail stuck in the onhover state and the tween over. Delaying the click action, will trigger the popup blocker.

Could it perhaps be possibru to load the target page somehow in the background and display the tab when the loading is complete? (so you won't have to stay and look at it while the images download)
How about a background worker from HTML5? - haven't looked much into those yet. Would probably still trigger the popup blocker.

Comment: RIAstar I haven't really ever worked too much with communication between the flash frame and anything outside of it (javascript, ajax). So if this is the case, it would be much appreciated if someone could point me to some sort of example.

Comment: Just promise me you won't be dropping background ads on your users...

Comment: Oh I see what you did there... I didn't think of that at all but I know those well; from PORN. I was working on a portfolio gallery and I was talking about what happens when you click on one of the thumbnails here: http://students.info.uaic.ro/~tudor.berechet/0sandbox/aperture/science/testing/GalleryAlpha.html

Comment: However, if you DO tell me how to do it, potential baddies can see and contribute to the nuisance that is those adds. It seems we're at an impasse here. How about you just link me some documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here's what I found out: it can't really be done. (if I'm wrong, please correct me!)

I saw how you can call external javascript from flash, and I used `popupWindow.blur()` and `window.focus()` to quickly get the focus back to the gallery window. However, doing this either triggers the popup blocker (in most cases), either gets ignored completely (and keeps focus on the new tab).

Thing is, whether new tabs are open in focus or in the background, is entirely up to the browser and the user's settings. This is why I asked if you can "trick" the browser into thinking that the user middle-clicked instead of left-clicked. Because in the scroll clicked case, most of the time it means "open in background tab" (in my personal experience at least).

Also, in case you want to use any sort of delay before the navigation occurs, it will always trigger the popup blocker.